# Converting date+time in Character format to CET while correctly taking into account daylight savings

Tags: r, datetime, dst, timestamp-with-timezone

I have a small problem converting some characters (the format is CET, they are just stored as characters). I want to change the format from characters to date, such that I can convert between timezones. Here is a small part of the data that I'm looking at.

```
timestamps <- c("2023-10-29 00:00:00", "2023-10-29 00:15:00", "2023-10-29 00:30:00", "2023-10-29 00:45:00", "2023-10-29 01:00:00", "2023-10-29 01:15:00", "2023-10-29 01:30:00", "2023-10-29 01:45:00", "2023-10-29 02:00:00", "2023-10-29 02:15:00", "2023-10-29 02:30:00", "2023-10-29 02:45:00", "2023-10-29 03:00:00", "2023-10-29 02:15:00", "2023-10-29 02:30:00", "2023-10-29 02:45:00", "2023-10-29 03:00:00", "2023-10-29 03:15:00", "2023-10-29 03:30:00", "2023-10-29 03:45:00", "2023-10-29 04:00:00", "2023-10-29 04:15:00")
```

My first attempt was doing the following:

```
as.POSIXct(timestamps, tz = "CET")
```

but that gives the following output:

```
 [1] "2023-10-29 00:00:00 CEST" "2023-10-29 00:15:00 CEST" "2023-10-29 00:30:00 CEST" "2023-10-29 00:45:00 CEST" "2023-10-29 01:00:00 CEST"
 [6] "2023-10-29 01:15:00 CEST" "2023-10-29 01:30:00 CEST" "2023-10-29 01:45:00 CEST" "2023-10-29 02:00:00 CEST" "2023-10-29 02:15:00 CET" 
[11] "2023-10-29 02:30:00 CET"  "2023-10-29 02:45:00 CET"  "2023-10-29 03:00:00 CET"  "2023-10-29 02:15:00 CET"  "2023-10-29 02:30:00 CET" 
[16] "2023-10-29 02:45:00 CET"  "2023-10-29 03:00:00 CET"  "2023-10-29 03:15:00 CET"  "2023-10-29 03:30:00 CET"  "2023-10-29 03:45:00 CET" 
[21] "2023-10-29 04:00:00 CET"  "2023-10-29 04:15:00 CET"
```

Here the CEST timezone is not properly allocated. They should be allocated up to the "2023-10-29 03:00:00" timestamp.

I also tried to use the "ymd_hms" from *lubridate*, but that did not do the trick either:

```
[1] "2023-10-29 00:00:00 CEST" "2023-10-29 00:15:00 CEST" "2023-10-29 00:30:00 CEST" "2023-10-29 00:45:00 CEST" "2023-10-29 01:00:00 CEST"
 [6] "2023-10-29 01:15:00 CEST" "2023-10-29 01:30:00 CEST" "2023-10-29 01:45:00 CEST" "2023-10-29 02:00:00 CET"  "2023-10-29 02:15:00 CET" 
[11] "2023-10-29 02:30:00 CET"  "2023-10-29 02:45:00 CET"  "2023-10-29 03:00:00 CET"  "2023-10-29 02:15:00 CET"  "2023-10-29 02:30:00 CET" 
[16] "2023-10-29 02:45:00 CET"  "2023-10-29 03:00:00 CET"  "2023-10-29 03:15:00 CET"  "2023-10-29 03:30:00 CET"  "2023-10-29 03:45:00 CET" 
[21] "2023-10-29 04:00:00 CET"  "2023-10-29 04:15:00 CET"
```

Actually, 1 less time period is now being assigned the "CEST" timezone compared to before.
Does anyone have a solution for this problem?

Comment: If you only have the dates as strings and not in any other form, I don't know how you would tell R which of the ambiguous strings are CET and which are CEST. Only Idea I have is to recreate the dates in R, doing something like `seq(timestamp_start,timestamp_end,by = '15 mins')` after you have converted the first and last timestamp if they are unambiguous.

Answer (score 0):

If you assume your data is sorted, you may add `+0100` for the (`duplicated`) `CET` times and `+0200` for the `CEST` times, and then add `%z` in the `as.POSIXct` call.

```
ifelse(duplicated(timestamps) | as.POSIXct(timestamps, tz = "CET") > as.POSIXct("2023-10-29 03:00:00"),
       paste0(timestamps, " +0100"),
       paste0(timestamps, " +0200")
       ) |> 
  as.POSIXct(format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S %z")
```

Gives:

```
[1] "2023-10-29 00:00:00 CEST" "2023-10-29 00:15:00 CEST" "2023-10-29 00:30:00 CEST" "2023-10-29 00:45:00 CEST" "2023-10-29 01:00:00 CEST" "2023-10-29 01:15:00 CEST"
 [7] "2023-10-29 01:30:00 CEST" "2023-10-29 01:45:00 CEST" "2023-10-29 02:00:00 CEST" "2023-10-29 02:15:00 CEST" "2023-10-29 02:30:00 CEST" "2023-10-29 02:45:00 CEST"
[13] "2023-10-29 02:00:00 CET"  "2023-10-29 02:15:00 CET"  "2023-10-29 02:30:00 CET"  "2023-10-29 02:45:00 CET"  "2023-10-29 03:00:00 CET"  "2023-10-29 03:15:00 CET" 
[19] "2023-10-29 03:30:00 CET"  "2023-10-29 03:45:00 CET"  "2023-10-29 04:00:00 CET"  "2023-10-29 04:15:00 CET"
```

> 